# Load HTML with javaScript in <a href...> link

Tags: javascript, html, linker

I am new to the programming world and currently only know `HTML`, `CSS`, `Java`, and about a week of JavaScript classes. My task is to create a website that has all these certain requirements. I have my skeleton `HTML` and `CSS` done and am just adding javaScript here and there.

My site has a main header logo area and a left and right column with news feeds, links, a calendar and whatnot. Currently i have about 8 pages with the same content in these areas. The center column is all that changes.

I would like to make it so that when a link is clicked (`a href="...`) it will load a javaScript function (with `.innerHTML="..";` in it) into my centerColumn `div` tag. So that if i want to update the right or left columns i don't have to change it on every single page.

I'm not set on using `.innerHTML` its just the only thing i know so far. If there is a better way or if you can import a whole `.html` file that would be fine.

I've tried many different things to no avail. Any help or suggestions would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: I'll probably get scolded for this, but if you want to try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it will be quite helpful. It wraps most of the common DOM operations in simple-to-use functions. What you're looking for is available in the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

Comment: Using some sort of templating system rather than JavaScript would be the correct way to go about this, should you want to do this for something besides educational value.

Comment: Would you be able to expand on this JQuery stuff? I just did a quick search and could only find things that included the use of PhP or things way over my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may use ajax, either jquery or javascript. Jquery is lot easier then javascript. I find $.ajax lot easier to use.

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"linktoyourajaxpage.php",
        data:{data:val1,data2:val2},
        cache:false,
        success:function(html){
            $("#resultdiv").html(html);

        }



    });
```

where resultdiv is the div where you want result to appear.

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to wait for the next milestone to do this. After talking with a friend at school he mentioned a neat way with php and that's the next step in our project after javascript. So Thanks all who replied :)